# RTSP Client Window play RTSP server Camera

Tags: mfc

i'm writing a program RTSP client Window MFC , but i don't know how to start, can you give me example, document, source code link etc..

Thank a lot

Comment: I suggest you start by creating a simple dialog based MFC project, perhaps with an CEdit window for debug info, and then integrate whatever RTSP library that you have chosen.

Comment: thank you, I was familiar with MFC, now i write program RTSP client, i find google, and i know library openRTSP live555 and libvlc support, but i don't know how to use it, any example thank.